# Finding the correct \fontfamily name

Tags: fonts

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to find the name of a font?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/15352/how-to-find-the-name-of-a-font)

I'm trying to use the TeX Gyre Chorus font for a small text (the rest of the document should use TeX Gyre Pagella). I've found the answer to use the `\fontfamily` command; however I just cannot find the correct name for TeX Gyre Chorus. Where should I look?

Answer (score 7):

If you look at `tgchorus.sty` you find that the family name is `qzc`.

Asking here is almost the same. `:-)`

Comment: How can we all available font names without opening the style file?

Comment: @SayOL Not a task I'd undertake.