# How to apply specific source in single piece?

Tags: fonts

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I use a particular font for a small section of text in my document?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/25249/how-do-i-use-a-particular-font-for-a-small-section-of-text-in-my-document)

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [change font of certain part of the text](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/2053/change-font-of-certain-part-of-the-text)

I need to use the font [Sans PT Caption](http://www.tug.dk/FontCatalogue/ptsanscaption/) only a snippet of text. How do I do that?

Comment: Another relevant duplicate might be [Finding the correct \fontfamily name](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/20287/2693). (Or both together.)  In this case the relevant package is `PTSansCaption.sty`, and the font name is `PTSansCaption-TLS`. I think we need a CommWiki question on this.

Comment: The family is phv http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/25249/how-do-i-use-a-particular-font-for-a-small-section-of-text-in-my-document Thanks.

Comment: for PTSansCaption, `phv` is *not* the correct font family name.  That's the family name for Helvetica.