# Fontfamily names

Tags: fonts, berry

Where can I find the `\fontfamily` names corresponding to the fonts I know?

I use `beamer`. Occasionally I want to use a particular font for the titles. I might use

```
\setbeamerfont{title}{family=\fontfamily{ppl}\selectfont}
```

to select the Palatino font that I know as `\usepackage{mathpazo}`. How/where can I find all the possible `\fontfamily` arguments and which font packages they correspond to?

Comment: Pretty much all questions tagged with {[tag:berry]} could be of interest here; on top of the two suggested duplicates particularly http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/12887/is-there-a-list-available-for-all-tex-fonts and http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/15352/how-to-find-the-name-of-a-font.